# Change position of animations in specific states

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, state-machine, animator

I’m currently trying to figure out how to change the position of an animation in a state.

I have a `GameObject` with a `SpriteRenderer` attached to the scene. The object also has an `AnimationController`. The state machine behind the controller has 3 states (without “AnyState”). An idle state, a state A and a state B with transitions: idle -> A -> B -> idle.

The animation of A is placed in the right side of the screen. So once the state machine runs, A is played on the right and B is played in the same position. But I want to play B on the left side of the screen. Is there any way to actually access the animations attached to states and position it accordingly?

I think I might be able to translate the object via script but I think it would require a lot of adjustments until it looks solid. I hope there’s an easier way.